# Usage difference between x86 RDRAND and RDSEED

Tags: random-number-generator, implementation, cryptographic-hardware, cpu

Modern x86 CPUs often have the RDRAND and RDSEED instructions for hardware generation of random numbers.  I just don't understand the difference between them.

Intel has this document: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/17/the-difference-between-rdrand-and-rdseed

But I don't understand how this affects the *usage* of RDRAND and RDSEED.  Namely, in what situations can I use each, for features like generating an encryption key, or for initial seeding of a PRNG?

As for the possibility of an NSA backdoor, that really isn't an issue for us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The processors come, at a first approximation, with three components:

1. A hardware noise source;
2. A pseudorandom generator that's periodically seeded from that noise source, whose output is available through the `RDRAND` instruction;
3. A true random generator that's driven off the noise source, whose output is available through the `RDSEED` instruction.

Intel's [longer documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide) has some explanations and a number of useful diagrams, which in turn refer to NIST's documents on random bit generators ([SP800-90A](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf), B and C).  But if I were to summarize the **security goals** of these two instructions, I think they are this:

- No bit of the output of `RDSEED` should be predictable to a **computationally unlimited** attacker who observes any other output bits at any other time.
- No bit of the output of `RDRAND` should be predictable to a **computationally limited** attacker who observes any other output bits at any other time.

  - But some such bits *might* be predictable to a **computationally unlimited** attacker under some circumstances.

In practical pseudorandom generators, even ones that reseed themselves periodically from fresh entropy input, it's generally the case that output bits are predictable from *nearby* bits, given enough computational effort.  For example, Intel's document tells us that their implementation of `RDRAND` uses NIST's CTR_DRBG algorithm.  This algorithm uses a block cipher in CTR mode to produce blocks of output data in caller-requested sizes, and the generator is only reseeded between output blocks.  So given a sufficient fragment of such a block, a brute force key recovery attack can predict the rest of the block with a better than chance success rate.

---

The document also tells us that both instructions use an "AES-CBC-MAC Based Conditioner" to process the output of the hardware entropy source.  This concept is explained in [NIST SP800-90B (second draft)](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-90/sp800-90b_second_draft.pdf) (p. 5):

> The optional conditioning component is a deterministic function responsible for reducing bias and/or increasing the entropy rate of the resulting output bits (if necessary to obtain a target value).

Basically, AES is here being used in a mode that, given true random but biased inputs, produces less biased, true random outputs.

---

Intel's document doesn't go at length about the "ENRNG" ("Enhanced Nondeterministc Random Number Generator," Intel's own term) used by `RDSEED`, but they refer us to NIST SP800-90B and [SP800-90C](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-90/sp800_90c_second_draft.pdf).  Looking at the latter in particular suggests that this "ENRNG" might also use AES, but again in a mode that maps true random inputs to true random outputs.  There doesn't seem to be enough information to tell exactly what's going on here, but reading between the lines I'm guessing it's one of the NRGB ("Nondeterministic Random Bit Generator") constructions from SP800-90C, section 9 (pp. 32ff), which combine the true random output with that of a pseudorandom generator in an entropy-preserving fashion, as a practical safety mechanism:

> The advantages of using these NRBGs include the following:
>
> - If the underlying DRBG mechanism in the NRBG has been instantiated securely, and the entropy source fails in an undetected manner, the NRBG will continue to provide random outputs, but at the security strength of the DRBG instantiation (the “fall-back” security strength), rather than providing outputs with full entropy.
> - Small deviations in the behavior of the entropy source in an NRBG will be masked by the DRBG output.

Comment: RdSeed follows the XOR construction NRBG in SP800-90C. That is - take a full entropy output from a (or the) conditioner and XOR it with an output from a (or the) DRBG. So the result has full entropy (according to the NIST definition of full entropy) and so RdSeed outputs can be safely concatenated to arbitrarily large key sizes. I can state this with some authority since I designed that circuit.

Answer (score 3):

The answer for usage, as intended with the design of the DRNG is this:

1) Use RdRand when you need a low latency random number - Rdrand won't underflow (cf never returns as 0). The docs say retry up to 10 times. This is not because RdRand will underflow. This is the claim Intel is making about future products - that a 10 round retry loop will always work on future products with a functioning RNG. To date no product has exhibited underflows on RdRand, but that is specifically not a guaranteed instruction behavior in future products.

2) RdRand can be safely used for cryptographic purposes in applications with a security strength up to O(2^128). This was fine in 2011. There is reason to want larger keys these days, which is where RdSeed comes in.

3) RdRand can be safely used for cryptographic purposes in applications with a security strength beyond O(2^128) by applying one of the algorithms in the SDG, but this is not super efficient and better to use RdSeed.

4) RdSeed can be used where full entropy is required - RdRand offers a computational prediction resistance lower bound, not full entropy.

5) RdSeed should be used when concatenating RdSeed numbers to make keys and other cryptographic random numbers that are larger than 128 bits. E.G. If you want a 256 bit secure random number, execute RdSeed until you have 256 bits of random data and concatenate it into the resulting 256 bit number.

Answer (score 1):

Note: most of those informations are Intel specific since there don't seem to be any AMD documents on how they do it.

**RDRAND**

Uses built-in AES-NI capability to generate high-entropy data for you. This includes some key whitening and produces different output every time you call it (since it generates this number just for you).

Is usually recommended if you just need high-entropy data, but possibly you might want to use OS-built CSPRNG instead (for example for PC's that don't have `RDRAND`).

**RDSEED**

Gives you current data from included entropy generator. Data is whitened on Intel CPU's (using AES-CBC). It can also report that no seed is currently available (when entropy source has been depleted), then return value will be 0, and target register set to 0 (confirmed on hardware). Seed isn't shared with `RDRAND` seed, but has same quality (goes trough same process of conditioning).

Recommended as entropy source for CSPRNGs. This should only be used for CSPRNGs vendors (possibly with other entropy sources, as PC might not have `RDSEED`).

**When to use**

When you need high-entropy numbers in low rates, use OS-built CSPRNGs. If you need high-entropy numbers in high rates and all your destination platforms have `RDRAND` (and you trust your CPU vendor), use `RDRAND`. If you are CSPRNG vendor, use `RDSEED` to gather additional entropy.

Comment: You should recheck the documentation on RDSEED. I'm pretty sure it also uses AES based post-processing, but also ensures that the output contains enough fresh entropy.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure there is any proper documentation about rdseed. Remember that Intel doesn't have monopoly on processors too ;) . I just based my claim on note somewhere that rdseed calls sometimes returned same values. But upon checking intel docs, seems that at least intel does some key whitening on rdseed. I don't think it's based on AES-NI, but I might be wrong.

Comment: There is definitely proper documentation. https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/17/the-difference-between-rdrand-and-rdseed which points to the detailed docs at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide

Comment: @rmalayter this is Intel specific documentation. It doesn't include how AMD does it. And there aren't really any manufacturer-independent docs that mention what guarantees rdrand/rdseed have. So AMD can do it their own way, and Intel can change this too. So to be specific: There is no manufacturer-independent documentation of rdrand.

Comment: I'm still skeptical about "Results can repeat"

Comment: @axapaxa I'm not sure you understand how this industry works. There is no standards body for x86 processors. The implementations define the standard behavior, so the Intel documentation is "official". AMD copies Intel or vice-versa depending on who introduced a feature.  Given that RDSEED is designed to seed a software CSPRNG, _results will not repeat_ with any probability higher than the birthday bound. So if you request 128 bits from RDSEED you'd have to do so 2^64 times to expect a repeat. In short, you're just plain wrong and spreading mis-information.

Comment: "Results can repeat" is something I found on Internet (can't find source now). I will try to confirm my information or disprove it, but you will have to wait, since most my machines run Ivy Bridge, which doesn't have RDSEED only RDRAND. @rmalayter I don't agree with how you see "copying features". Especially with this instruction, there is a lot going behind scenes, which Intel doesn't fully explain (and probably AMD doesn't fully copy). Instead of claiming I'm wrong, please do your check, just like I will.

Comment: @axapaxa the burden is on you my friend... extraordinary claims require proof. My claim is only that RDRAND and RDSEED work just as Intel has described in great detail. If RDSEED re-used outputs I think it might have made the news.

Comment: I have tested this on i7-6700HQ, indeed RDSEED doesn't reuse output. @rmalayter it isn't extraordinary, it could re-used it if entropy was depleted for example. This doesn't seem to be case in my limited testing. You might believe Intel docs, but personally I know Intel for inexact specs, just look how bswap behaves on words or setalc which wasn't documented on Intel for 20+ years... Anyway, removed my wrong claim which I found somewhere.

Comment: The chip generates 3Gbits/sec of entropy. It won't run out. That's the whole point.

Comment: @rmalayter 3Gbits/sec is nothing for 3Ghz CPU that can extract 32bits every few cycles (and it probably is only 1.5Gbit for rdseed). I found out that it was mistake in my testing upon checking results. But it's so much easier to not trust doc if it complies with your mind. Anyway, what's wrong with my answer that my downvote was never removed and I was never upvoted? Because clearly there still must be something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Perhaps you might care to add to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40954/why-do-cryptographers-need-loads-of-true-random-numbers if you feel that 3Gb/s is insufficient for cryptographic use...

Comment: The DRNG does not use any part of AES-NI. It has a built in hardware AES circuit that is specifically designed for the CTR-DRBG algorithm in the sense that it has an inline key schedule, since the key is updated for every invocation of the function.

Comment: I'm not sure what "RDSEED doesn't reuse output" means. RdSeed is precisely defined as an SP800-90C XOR construction NRBG fed by an AES-CTR-DRBG and and AES-CBC-MAC conditioner that in turn is fed by a step-feedback metastable entropy source. The resulting data meets NIST's definition of full entropy.